# SonarQube 5.6.2 plugin - custom Extension point does not get executed

Tags: java, sonarqube5.6

I have added an interface 'FileGenerator' as an **extension point** and implementation class 'JavaFileGenerator' is added implementing to the interface/extension point however the implementation class is not getting executed.
I have below classes in my sonar plugin

1. MyPlugin class implementing Plugin interface where I have registered
   my extension class 'JavaFileGenerator'
2. FileGenerator is annotated with @ExtensionPoint,
   @BatchSide/@ServerSide
3. In JavaFileGenerator class FileSystem is injected in constructor of
   the class

   ```
    public class MyPlugin implements Plugin {
     @Override
     public void define(Context context) {
      context.addExtension(JavaFileGenerator.class); }
   }
       @BatchSide
       @ExtensionPoint
        public interface FileGenerator {
           void generateFile();
        }
        public class JavaFileGenerator implements FileGenerator{
        private FileSystem fileSystem;

           public JavaFileGenerator(final FileSystem fileSystem){
               this.fileSystem=fileSystem; }
            @Override
            public void generateFile() { ... }
           }
   ```

JavaFileGenerator class does not get executed. Anybody has any idea about this?

Comment: Actually the fact is that I should not access the FileSystem before the Sensor phase as "Accessing the filesystem before the Sensor phase is deprecated and is not supported" in newer versions of sonarQube like 5.6 and above. So the way I am doing is not correct and I should find some other way to do my task :)

Answer (score 0):

for example, for action at the end of analyse on client side you can write a plugin as  :

```
@BatchSide
public class XXXPostJob implements PostJob {

@Override
public void describe(PostJobDescriptor descriptor) {
    descriptor.name("-- post client side analyse sonarqube plugin --");
}

@Override
public void execute(PostJobContext context) {

// your business here ...

    }
```